# Introducing derivatives and integrals to solve for physics equations

Tags: integration, derivatives, physics

I recently came across this line of reasoning in a physics textbook:

[image]

I'm having trouble following this. On the left hand side of line 2, how do we get $2\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{d (dx/dt)^2}{dt}$? Looks like it might be the chain rule, but I'm a bit uncomfortable throwing these $dx$ and $dt$ terms around like this.

Then on line 3, we seem to be multiplying both sides by $\int dt$, but over a different interval? How does this work?

Comment: It is indeed the chain rule, and you're then integrating both sides with respect to $t$, changing the variables on the one side, while being a tiny bit sloppy with notation.

Comment: you are not throwing anything around - $(\dot x(t))^2$ is a function of time, whose derivative by the chain rule is exactly $2 \dot x \frac{d(\dot x)}{dt} = 2 \dot x \ddot x$

Comment: Is the text above from Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems by Marion and Norton. I was assigned that book when I took an upper level classical mechanics course. Hated it. If you're looking for additional texts at a similar level, I posted some recommendations at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit (I'm going to use $v$ and $\dot{x}$ interchangeably... sometimes it is convenient to use $v$ and other times it is convenient to use $\dot{x}$): 
So starting from
$$\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {{{\dot x}^2}} \right) = \frac{d}{{dt}}\left[ {{{\left( {\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}} \right)}^2}} \right]$$
...we'll let
$$v = \frac{{dx}}{{dt}} = \dot x$$
...and we'll let
$$h\left( v \right) = {v^2} = {\left( {\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}} \right)^2} = {{\dot x}^2}$$

From the definitions of v and h, plus the first equation, we get:
$$\frac{{dh\left( v \right)}}{{dt}} =\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {{{\dot x}^2}} \right) = \frac{d}{{dt}}\left[ {{{\left( {\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}} \right)}^2}} \right] = \frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {{v^2}} \right) $$

Using the equation above... and the chain rule:
$$\frac{{dh}}{{dt}} = \frac{{dh}}{{dv}}\frac{{dv}}{{dt}}$$
...it follows that:

$$\frac{{dh}}{{dt}} = \frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {{{\dot x}^2}} \right) = \frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {{v^2}} \right) = \frac{{dh}}{{dv}}\frac{{dv}}{{dt}} = \underbrace {\frac{d}{{dv}}\left( {{v^2}} \right)}_{2v}\underbrace {\frac{{dv}}{{dt}}}_{\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}} \right) = \frac{{{d^2}x}}{{d{t^2}}} = \ddot x} = 2v\ddot x = 2\dot x\ddot x$$

Next... the integral on the left side of the bottom equation you posted...Remembering that $h(v) = v^2$ and $\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\dot{x}\right)$... from the fundamental theorem of calculus
...
$$\int_{{t_i}}^{{t_f}} {\frac{{dh}}{{dt}}dt = h\left( {{t_f}} \right) - h\left( {{t_i}} \right)} = {v^2}\left( {{t_f}} \right) - {v^2}\left( {{t_i}} \right)  $$

Going back to the chain rule...
$$\frac{{dh}}{{dt}} = \frac{{dh}}{{dv}}\frac{{dv}}{{dt}} = \frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {{v^2}} \right) = \frac{d}{{dt}}{\left( {\dot x} \right)^2}$$
...from the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus...
$$\int_{{t_i}}^{{t_f}} {\frac{{dh\left( {v\left( t \right)} \right)}}{{dt}}dt = \int_{{t_i}}^{{t_f}} {\frac{{dh}}{{dv}}\frac{{dv}}{{dt}}dt}  = \int_{{t_i}}^{{t_f}} {\frac{d}{{dt}}{{\left( {\dot x} \right)}^2}dt}  = h\left( {v\left( {{t_f}} \right)} \right) - h\left( {v\left( {{t_i}} \right)} \right)}  \\ =  {v^2_f}\left( {{t_f}} \right) - {v^2_i}\left( {{t_i}} \right)$$

But thanks to the chain rule... we can basically act like the differentials in the derivatives above multiply like fractions..(and use what is called 'integration by substitution')
$$\int_{{t_i}}^{{t_f}} {\frac{{dh}}{{dv}}\frac{{dv}}{{dt}}dt}  = \int_{{t_i}}^{{t_f}} {dh}  = \int_{{t_i}}^{{t_f}} {\frac{{dh}}{{dt}}dt}  = \int_{{t_i}}^{{t_f}} {\frac{d}{{dt}}\left[ {{{\left( {\dot x} \right)}^2}} \right] = } \int_{{v_i}}^{{v_f}} {\frac{d}{{dt}}\left[ {{{\left( {\dot x} \right)}^2}} \right]dt}  = \left. {{{\left( {\dot x} \right)}^2}} \right|_{{v_i}}^{{v_f}} = \left. {{v^2}} \right|_{{v_o}}^{{v_f}} = v_f^2 - v_o^2$$

For the integral on the right side of the third equation... since $g \sin{\theta}$ is a constant...if $b = g\sin{\theta}$... From the fundamental theorem of calculus, 
$$b\int_{{t_0}}^{{t_f}} {\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}dt}  = \left. {bx} \right|_{{t_0}}^{{t_f}} = b\left[ {x\left( {{t_f}} \right) - x\left( {{t_o}} \right)} \right] = b\left[ {{x_f} - {x_0}} \right]$$

But we could get the same answer by using sloppy notation and 'cancelling out' the dt's as follows:
$$b\int_{{t_0}}^{{t_f}} {\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}dt}   = b\int_{{x_0}}^{{x_f}} {dx}  = \left. {bx} \right|_{{x_o}}^{{x_f}} = b\left[ {{x_f} - {x_o}} \right]$$

Is the text that you posted by from Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems by Marion and Norton. I was assigned that book when I took an upper level classical mechanics course. Hated it. If you're looking for additional texts at a similar level, here's some recommendations.

[Classical Mechanics by John Taylor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/189138922X)

[Analytical Mechanics by Grant Fowles and George Cassidy (you can buy the international edition for about $12)

[Classical Mechanics by R. Douglas Gregory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AKE1QL8)

[Classical Mechanics by Tom Kibble](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1860944353) (costs just $30 new)

[Introduction to Classical Mechanics by David Morin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521876222)

Comment: This is indeed coming from Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems by Marion and Norton. I was trying to use this for self-study but if they are this hand-wavy this early I should probably consider other options. I chose this text because it covers Hamiltonian dynamics, which I would like to learn about. Thank you for the other book suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are studying on your own, I would definitely recommend you pick another book. I didn't poll my entire class, but pretty much everyone seemed to hate the Marion and Norton book. I just have a bachelor of science in physics... so I don't know if Marion and Norton is a good book for preparing for graduate school... If you aren't planning on going to graduate school...of all the books I mentioned, the book by John Taylor was my favorite. It was by far the clearest, in my opinion. I have no clue if it is a good book for preparing for graduate school.